# How to force Android Studio to rebuild "unused" classes when modified

Tags: android-studio, build

I'm working on a project that recreate several objects with Gson. Most of those object/classes are rightfully grayed out (as never called) by Android Studio.

The problem is that when I make some changes to those grayed out classes, some times, they don't get rebuilt when I run the app. Resulting in the app deployed to the emulator, having and old build version of the class I just modified. This makes debugging very frustrating and time consuming, sometime making you think you have some bugs while in fact there isn't.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio that those classes needs to be treated like other regular "in use" classes? Without having to rebuild the entire project of course.

I've tried to find a solution online, but maybe I didn't find the right keyword combo.

Maybe I was experiencing some kind of bug?